# how to handle Listagg size limit in redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

```
select customer_id, 
LISTAGG(distinct order_id::varchar, '|') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY order_id) AS orders
from table
group by customer_id
```

Message:ERROR: Result size exceeds LISTAGG limit Detail: error: Result size exceeds LISTAGG limit code: 8001 context: LISTAGG limit: 65535

How to overcome the error?

Answer (score 2):

64K bytes for varchar is a hard limit in Redshift.  So you cannot extend it that way.

There are a couple of approaches you could take.  The first would be to limit the number of order_ids that are in varchar.  You could pre-process you data to add a number as to which N thousand the order_id is in.  Let's say your order_id is 8 bytes in size so you could have 8,000 order_ids in one list_agg.  Number the first 8,000 with 1, the second 8,000 with 2 ...  then group by customer_id and number.  Now when you use the result you will need to look at all the numbers for a given customer_id.  Not perfect but gets you past this issue.  (This is what the system table stl_querytext is set up.)

Or you could change how you are storing the information.  A SUPER data type column can store 1MB of data (soon to be 16MB with some restrictions on what you can do with it at this larger size).  So you could take your numbered list_agg() results above and combine them into a super array.

If your data is bigger than this I'd suggest that you look into doing some form of blob storage in S3 and reference these from Redshift.  Really big quanta of data are not really good to have in a relational database.

=====================================

Per request for an example:

Here's a quick test case to show one way to do this.  I made it on a Postgres fiddle so you can play with it but that means using string_agg() in stead of list_agg() but that are nearly identical (actually list_agg() is more flexible).

Set up some data:

```
create table test as 
select 1 as customer_id, 1 as order_id
union all
select 1 as customer_id, 1 as order_id
union all
select 1 as customer_id, 2 as order_id
union all
select 2 as customer_id, 1 as order_id
union all
select 2 as customer_id, 2 as order_id
union all
select 2 as customer_id, 3 as order_id
union all
select 1 as customer_id, 13 as order_id
union all
select 1 as customer_id, 4 as order_id
union all
select 2 as customer_id, 13 as order_id
union all
select 2 as customer_id, 14 as order_id
union all
select 2 as customer_id, 15 as order_id;
```

Query (you can flatten this by one level on Redshift):

```
with dists as (
  select customer_id, order_id 
  from test
  group by customer_id, order_id
  ),
cnts as (
  select customer_id, order_id, 
  (3 - 1 + row_number() over (partition by customer_id order by order_id))::int / 3 AS cnt
  from dists
  )
select customer_id, cnt,
STRING_AGG(order_id::varchar, '|' ORDER BY order_id)  AS orders
from cnts
group by customer_id, cnt;
```

Fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ff2a8/16

Comment: Thanks. Can you please share sql steps for approach #1? My order id is 20 bytes in length